# Rails flash doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rails app, and I'm trying to have flash display an error message and redirect to the sign in page if a somebody who hasn't logged in tries to edit a user's page. It does redirect to the sign in page but doesn't display the flash

```
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

 def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please signin to access this page."
  end


app/controllers/users_controller.rb

private
    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?    
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Are your template or layout files actually checking to see if there *are* notices and appropriately injecting them into your HTML?

Check your `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`. You should probably have a line in there, or in another template, which checks for flashes or alerts and displays them if present.